# Java OO MVC problem

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller

I have "HighScoreModel", "HighScoreController", "HighScoreView"

Everything works between model<->controller but, how do I get the
data to my view?

I have a public model[] in my controller so I can access it from my view. Just wondering if it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the View is an observer of the Model. So when the Model changes, it notifies the View which renders itself accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

well , you need FormBean to get the data to view. FormBean holds the data, pass from controller to view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want specifics you will need to tell us which framework you are using.
Spring MVC?
JSF?
Swing?
Struts?

If you are rolling your own then perhaps it would be a good idea to look at an actual implementation to see how it's been done before.

Comment: It's Android. Now I have a public model[] in my controller so I can access it from my view. Just wondering if it is the right way